# Loading SASS Variables in ES6

Tags: javascript, sass, ecmascript-6

How does one use a SASS variable in an ES6 file?

```
import base from '../../../styles/_base.scss'

const styles = {
  cardHeader: {
    backgroundColor: base.neutralColorLight  // Does not work
  }
}

<CardHeader style={styles.cardHeader} />
```

The stylesheet:

```
// _base.scss

$neutral-color-light: rgb(232, 232, 232);
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(base);` and checked what you get? I'm not sure this is a supported feature, but since I don't know your setup, I can't really say.

Comment: @nils the result is empty.  Wonder what I can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use `node-sass-json-vars`

The npm package [node-sass-json-vars](https://github.com/Updater/node-sass-json-importer) allows you to specify json files in `@import`. Since you can also `import` json files in javascript, this allows for easy usage between the two.

To use it, you'd install `node-sass-json-importer` with NPM and specify it as an importer on the command line:

```
./node_modules/.bin/node-sass --importer node_modules/node-sass-json-importer/dist/node-sass-json-importer.js MySASSFile.scss
```

In your sass file, you wouldn't specify the variables, instead leaving that to the json file:

```
@import 'colors.json'

.neutral-thing {
  color: $neutral-color-light
}
```

And you would do the following in the json file:

```
{
  "neutral-color-light": "rgb(232, 232, 232)"
}
```

And in your JS file, just import the json:

```
import colors from './colors.json'

const styles = {
  cardHeader: {
    backgroundColor: colors.neutral-color-light
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice.  Will give it a shot.

Comment: The last line won't work: `backgroundColor: colors.neutral-color-light`. Need camelCase or quoting.

Comment: For gulp users, you can use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass-json